# Can I include composer.phar in my project like a class library?

Tags: php, composer-php, phar

I want to use that feature in order to set dependencies right via web interface.

I have found in  [Using Phar Archives: Introduction](http://www.php.net/manual/en/phar.using.intro.php) tutorial that it's possible to do next:

```
<?php
include 'composer.phar';
?>
```

But i get next error when trying to do same:

```
phar "/var/www/.../composer.phar" is API version 0.0.0, and cannot be processed

#0 /var/www/.../composer.phar(13): Phar::mapPhar('composer.phar') 
...
```

My phpinfo output shows next information:

Phar EXT version       2.0.1,
 Phar API version   1.1.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<strike>You need to do:</strike>

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
use <NAMESPACE>\<LIBRARY>;
```

to load whatever your composer libraries are.  **composer.phar** is the script that actually goes and retrieves libraries for you, based on the contents of your **composer.json** file.

If you want to actually run **composer.phar** from a PHP script, keep it simple and just use the shell (e.g. using backticks, shell_exec(), etc).

```
$output = `<path_to_composer>/composer.phar [options]`;
```

What you're trying to do is meant for *libraries* that have been packaged as a **phar**, not applications.

Comment: I think OP actually wants to execute composer-related actions.

Comment: @Evert I'll let him clarify - I'm not sure why you'd want to do that from a PHP script.  Hmm, re-reading, I think you're right.

Comment: Thanks guys. 
0.Yes, @Evert is right. 1.I can not use a shell and shell_exec.